# apt working unexpectedly on debian 8

Tags: debian, apt, bandwidth

Sometimes I'm noticing my bandwidth being all consumed although I'm not doing anything consuming, so I fire up `nethogs` on my wireless interface and I notice an `apt` process running without me starting it, and without for example using `cron`, and although I'm using Linux since about 6 years I never noticed it does anything without me asking to, so what have I done wrong?

```
uname -a
3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1 (2015-05-24) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Edit: I googled the exact process path and found this  [same question as mine on ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33530/usr-lib-apt-methods-http-eating-my-bandwidth) but the answers don't explain why it's working autonomously on my machine!

[image: apt process eating bandwidth]

Comment: In addition to `cron-apt`, there's also a package named `apticron` which does pretty much the same. But how do you know it's not `cron` related? Have you done something like `grep -R apt /etc/cron*` and checked each of the matches that it is not related?

Comment: Well, I think I know it's not `cron` related because I know `cron` and what it does and don't remember using it or any related package (has the word "cron" in its name). And I've just checked for apticron and it's not installed, but anyway thanks for the suggested command, I'll try it when the problem happens again. or do `ps aux | grep cron`.

Comment: I found a `cron` process running but I listed root's `cron` jobs and there aren't any: root@Baha-laptop:baha# crontab -l
no crontab for root

Comment: Try `pstree` or something like `ps axjf` when the job is running again to see what process started it.

Comment: I `dist-upgrade`d the system with 200 MB yesterday, so I suspect it won't happen soon, but I'll check if it does.

Answer (score 1):

It's probable you have installed the [package `cron-apt`](https://www.debian-administration.org/article/162/A_short_introduction_to_cron-apt), which runs `apt-get update` at regular intervals.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I don't think `cron` has anything to do with this, because I never came close to using it yet!
And when I checked, bash told me that `cron-apt` isn't installed and told me to `apt-get install cron-apt` if I wanted!

Comment: @Baha_hi fair enough. You might want to update your question to include this information for others to see.

Comment: A proper way to check whether the package is installed is `dpkg -l cron-apt`. Do not depend on Bash magic, ask the package manager.